# Understanding route matching in standard go ServeMux

Tags: go

I'm having some problems understanding routing rules from the standard GO library http://godoc.org/net/http#ServeMux. Matching pattern "/about" does "GET /about" but does not update the browser with the new html. The html remains the same as for "GET /". I have tried changing the patterns to "/about/" but has the unexpected effect of the submitted form generating a "GET /form" instead of a "POST /form". The code below should make this question clearer. Is this normal behaviour?

Here is a screen capture [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucu5pIm3NL4] showing this behaviour.

I'm using Go 1.8.3 on Windows 10. The behaviour is the same in Google Chrome and Firefox.

I also tried Go 1.7.6, but the behaviour was the same.

Thanks for your help.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "io"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    // These 3 lines are what I expect to work, but it has a problem
    http.HandleFunc("/", index)         // does GET /
    http.HandleFunc("/about", about)    // does GET /about. URL in address
                                        // bar changes to
                                        // http://localhost:8080/about/,
                                        // but html does not change.
                                        // The html code for INDEX remains
                                        // in browser
    http.HandleFunc("/form", form)      // does GET /form and included form
                                        // does POST /form

    //http.HandleFunc("/", index)       // does GET /
    //http.HandleFunc("/about/", about) // does GET /about
    //http.HandleFunc("/form/", form)   // does GET /form and included form
                                        // also does GET /form. Does not
                                        // do POST /form

    // This code works as expected
    //http.HandleFunc("/", index)       // does GET /
    //http.HandleFunc("/about/", about) // does GET /about
    //http.HandleFunc("/form", form)    // does GET /form and included form
                                        // does /POST form as expected

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(req.Method + req.URL.Path)
    io.WriteString(w, `<html><head></head>
                        <body>INDEX
                        <a href="/">INDEX</a>
                        <a href="/about">ABOUT</a>
                        <a href="/form">FORM</a>
                        </body></html>
                        `)
}

func about(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(req.Method + req.URL.Path)
    io.WriteString(w, `<html><head></head>
                        <body>ABOUT
                        <a href="/">INDEX</a>
                        <a href="/about">ABOUT</a>
                        <a href="/form">FORM</a>
                        </body></html>
                        `)
}

func form(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    if req.Method == http.MethodPost {
        fmt.Println(req.Method + req.URL.Path)
        io.WriteString(w, `<html><head></head>
                        <body>PROCESS FORM
                        <a href="/">INDEX</a>
                        <a href="/about">ABOUT</a>
                        <a href="/form">FORM</a>
                        </body></html>
                        `)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(req.Method + req.URL.Path)
    io.WriteString(w, `<html><head></head>
                        <body>FORM
                        <a href="/">INDEX</a>
                        <a href="/about">ABOUT</a>
                        <a href="/form">FORM</a>
                        <form method="POST" action="/form"><input type="submit"></form>
                        </body></html>
                        `)

}
```

Comment: It does change. You many not be noticing it as the text on those pages is almost same. Try adding more text on about page and you will notice the change. Tried your code on MacOS with go version 1.7.3.

Comment: @sahaj8 I've added a YouTube screen capture to show the problem I'm having. Could it be a bug with Windows, if it's working fine on your Mac?

Comment: Note the difference in going to /about/ vs /about , sahaj is probably going to /about while the video of gim is going to /about/  - consider doing `http.HandleFunc("/about/", about) ` and read https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux carefully

Comment: On Mac, on clicking on about the URL appears as "http://localhost:8080/about" and not with trailing '/'.

Comment: Looks like some issue in Go. Check here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11757

Comment: Today I ran the code with http.HandleFunc("/", index);http.HandleFunc("/about", about);http.HandleFunc("/form", form) again - all routes without any trailing slash. And it's now working in Chrome, Opera, Internet Explorer and Edge. In all cases no trailing slash is added to the URLs by the browser.

Comment: However, Firefox seems to still be adding a trailing slash to the "about" URL and thus causing the problem that the html for the about page does not load into the browser. I came across this Firefox bug (but it's for iOS and has been resolved for iOS) "Stop appending a forward slash to every URL" https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1201079.

Comment: It looks like this was a browser caching problem.